# Implicit conversion operator overloading re-using the same code

Tags: c#

I have several implicit conversion operator overloads and they're all using exactly the same code. How would I go about refactoring it?
I would like the flexibility of being able to add more implicit operator overloads without needing to change the class everytime.

I tried to think of a design pattern that might come in handy. Builder or Strategy came to mind but I'm not sure about it.

Note: the Binary.ToBitArray() has 3 method overloads - one that takes a string parameter, one that takes an int parameter and one that takes a long parameter. That's how I'm able to use the same code.

```
    public static implicit operator Register(string binaryNumber)
    {
        //Converting binaryNumber into a BitArray
        BitArray registerBits = Binary.ToBitArray(binaryNumber);

        return new Register(registerBits);
    }

    public static implicit operator Register(int binaryNumber)
    {
        //Converting binaryNumber into a BitArray
        BitArray registerBits = Binary.ToBitArray(binaryNumber);

        return new Register(registerBits);
    }

    public static implicit operator Register(long binaryNumber)
    {
        //Converting binaryNumber into a BitArray   
        BitArray registerBits = Binary.ToBitArray(binaryNumber);

        return new Register(registerBits);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactically the code is the same, but you're actually calling three different functions in your methods.

You *could* use `dynamic` to defer the binding until runtime, but this exposes some risks:

- Your code is no longer type-safe. Callers have no idea what types are valid as parameters
- Bugs are not discoverable at compile-time. Someone else could call your implicit operator on, say, a boolean, and you wouldn't know anything was wrong until runtime.

IMHO the potential risks are not worth saving a little bit of (mostly) duplicate code.